Someone can help with intuitive explanations for "Circularly Gaussian distribution"?
I am reading one article APPENDIX 2
The Probability Density Function of the Difference Between Non-Negative Components that defines the probability density of the sum of two random variables. Wiki only gives one simple sentence here, without specific contents for the introduction of circular.
The definition:
A complex random vector $\mathbf{Z}$ is called circularly symmetric if for every deterministic $\varphi \in [-\pi,\pi)$ the distribution of $e^{\mathrm i \varphi}\mathbf{Z}$ equals the distribution of $\mathbf{Z}$
Without expertise on statistics, I could not catch much clue about what the text is saying. Some plain equations might be much more helpful.
Has circular some connection to the zero-mean or just plain absolute operation here?

What is the backgrounds for this term (that has) to be introduced?
Appreciate if some references can be directed (hopefully including fundamental ones)?

In the very link you provided WP clearly defines what circular symmetry means. Does this not explain the backgrounds for this term?

Sorry, I expected some could help to translate the "statistics language" to plain words or equations, most expecting some intuitive.

It's like how the Gaussian is rotationally invariant. Multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ corresponds to rotation in the plane.

Thanks @Andrew! If it is 2D Gaussian distribution rotating about the normal of the plane, this is understandable, but I am lost for a vector $\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{X}+i\mathbf{Y}$.

You wrote that answer in complex analysis eight years ago and today ask what $e^{i\phi}$ does to a complex $Z$ ?

Thanks for your comments! @Kurt G. Yes, i might understand the rotation operation by multiplying $e^{i\phi}$, but is this meant in the context? Oh, you might have seen the Apppendix, is the circular just implying the absolute sign (or rotation invariant) since $|e^{i\phi}B_{iu}|=|B_{iu}|$?

Correct. Their rotation of the complex $Z$ is geometrically the same as rotating vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ just using a different tool, $e^{i\varphi}$ versus a $2\times 2$ matrix. Don't overthink this.

Thank you very much @Kurt G.
